# NestJS - How/Where to configure FileInterceptor with async way

Tags: node.js, file-upload, interceptor, multer, nestjs

As the documentation says: we can have an async configuration for the file interceptor.

I would like to use this to use my `ConfigService` for the upload directory (who is different by environment).
But I don't know where to write this async configuration.

The documentation give us an example to set the configuration but I don't know how to integrated this to my project.

I have check the official documentation and especially the `Techniques/File Upload` and `Overview/Middleware`. I have tested some implementation but my configuration seems to be never used.

I use this method to configue Multer:

```
MulterModule.registerAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    storage: diskStorage({
      destination: configService.downloadFolder,
      filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const randomName = Array(32)
          .fill(null)
          .map(() => Math.round(Math.random() * 16).toString(16))
          .join('')
        return cb(null, `${randomName}${extname(file.originalname)}`)
      }
    })
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService]
})
```

Do you have any idea how to integrate this configuration?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: This works for me. What does your controller look like? Does it work when you use `MulterModule.register` with static values?

Comment: Hey @KimKern ! I didn't test this method (`MulterModule.register`).
My upload works only with the decorator `@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor(...))`.
Where do you put the `MulterModule.registerAsync` ?

Comment: Have a look at my answer on where to put the `registerAsync`.

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay; I had to put my project on hold.
Your solution is good, thanks @KimKern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to import `MulterModule` in your `AppModule` to set the default configuration:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MulterModule.registerAsync(...)
  ],
})
export class AppModule{}
```

Comment: I have two features modules where I actually process the uploaded files. 
If I import MulterModule in my AppModule, the registered storage service is not working. 
So apparently I need to import MulterModule in all the feature modules, but in there, dependency injection is not working. So I'm stuck with this.